# How to get the TailwindCSS Prettier Plugin to work with Svelte

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, prettier

I asked on the official Discord, no one answered, I have dug through all sorts of information online and nothing has worked.

Basically, I want to get the TailwindCSS plugin for Prettier up and running, so I can order my classes consistently in my SvelteKit project, and I am having no luck.

I have followed all sorts of tutorials, like [this one](https://joyofcode.xyz/sveltekit-with-tailwind-css), to a tee and nothing is working. I have uninstalled the Svelte Prettier plugin, restarted VSCode, changed my config file, restarted VSCode again, and again.

Here are my config files:

`.prettierrc`:

```
{
    "useTabs": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "printWidth": 100,
    "pluginSearchDirs": ["."]
}
```

`settings.json`:

```
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Atom One Light",
  "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code",
  "editor.fontLigatures": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[svelte]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "svelte.svelte-vscode"
  },
  "svelte.enable-ts-plugin": true,
  "prettier.plugins": ["prettier-plugin-tailwindcss"],
  "git.confirmSync": false,
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "workbench.productIconTheme": "emoji-product-icons-fun",
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "git.enableSmartCommit": true
}
```

Maybe I'm missing something really basic. How can I fix it? I have got the plugin working in my `app.postcss` file, but not in `.svelte` files.

Comment: Yes please, provide your config files. Readers probably can't answer the question in the current state, as there is not enough information to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out!

1. Make sure your `tailwind-css prettier` plugin is installed properly.Run this code.

```
npm install --save-dev tailwindcss-prettier
```

2. Add this line to `settings.json`

```
"prettier.plugins": [
    "tailwindcss-prettier"
  ]
```

3. Add finally configure prettier with svelte using this in your `settings.json`

```
"prettier.parser": "svelte"
```

Note: If your project is using postcss config file, you can configure it to use tailwindcss-prettier.

Comment: How do I configure the postcss file to use it?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is:

- Install "prettier-plugin-svelte" and "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss"
- create a .prettierrc and add the following:

```
{
  "parser": "svelte",
  "plugins": ["prettier-plugin-tailwindcss"]
}
```

```
pnpm i -D prettier-plugin-svelte prettier-plugin-tailwindcss
```

(If you are using npm or yarn, just switch out the "pnpm")