# how to use prettier-plugin-svelte with prettier-plugin-tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, vscode-extensions, prettier, prettier-vscode

I'm trying to use prettier to format svelte files with tailwind classes, so that tailwind utilities classes get automatically sorted following [tailwind's recommended order](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/automatic-class-sorting-with-prettier#how-classes-are-sorted)

I followed this docs:

- [prettier-plugin-svelte with prettier-plugin-tailwindcss](https://github.com/sveltejs/prettier-plugin-svelte#usage-with-tailwind-prettier-plugin)

but when I try to format any svelte file I get a "Extension 'Prettier - Code Formatter' is configured as formatter but it cannot format 'Svelte' files"

[image]

And when I try to configure it the only available option is:

[image]

these are the steps I took:

```bash
pnpn create svelte@latest svelte-prettier-tailwindcss

◇ Which Svelte app template?
│ Skeleton project
│
◇ Add type checking with TypeScript?
│ Yes, using TypeScript syntax
│
◇ Select additional options (use arrow keys/space bar)
│ Add Prettier for code formatting

pnpn exec svelte-add@latest tailwindcss

pnpm install -D prettier prettier-plugin-tailwindcss
```

this is my `.prettierrc` file

```json
{
    "useTabs": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "printWidth": 100,
    "plugins": ["prettier-plugin-svelte", "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss"],
    "pluginSearchDirs": false,
    "overrides": [{ "files": "*.svelte", "options": { "parser": "svelte" } }]
}
```

and this is my `./vscode/settings.json` file

```json
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "[svelte]": {
        // "editor.defaultFormatter": "svelte.svelte-vscode" // this works, but it doesn't use tailwindcss plugin!
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" // this doesn't work
    }
}
```

Then I create this `+page.svelte` page

```html
<h1 class="text-sm bg-fuchsia-200">Tailwind will reformat this (text-sm goes last)</h1>

<p>Visit <a href="https://kit.svelte.dev">kit.svelte.dev</a> to read the documentation</p>
```

If I run `pnpm run format` the prettier tailwindcss uses the tailwind css pluing

but if I press ctrl-shift-I (or ctrl-shift-P format document) I get the error about prettier code not being able to format svelte files.

Any idea?

Comment: [How to get the TailwindCSS Prettier Plugin to work with Svelte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75229724/14945696), does this by any chance works? [Also...?](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/1376#issuecomment-1412457061)

Comment: thanks a lot for the links, checked them, but I think I found the issue, see my own answer

Answer (score 3):

I had to add `"prettier.documentSelectors": ["**/*.svelte"]` to my vscode settings file

The reason for this option is explained [here](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#prettierdocumentselectors)

Since `prettier-plugin-svelte` is overriding svelte files from the `.prietterrc` file (with `{ files: ['*.svelte'], options: { parser: 'svelte' } }`) we also need to let the prettier vscode extension know that it can handle svelte files.

this is how my `settings.json` ended up:

```json
{
    "prettier.documentSelectors": ["**/*.svelte"],
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "svelte.enable-ts-plugin": true
}
```

and this is the `.prettierrc` file

```json
{
    "useTabs": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "printWidth": 100,
    "plugins": ["prettier-plugin-svelte", "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss"],
    "pluginSearchDirs": false,
    "overrides": [{ "files": "*.svelte", "options": { "parser": "svelte" } }]
}
```